# How do I send sample emails to my Facebook test users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A test user on Facebook has a default @tfbnw.net email address as the primary email address, in addition to a @facebook.com address which routes to their Facebook Messages inbox.

I've tried to set the @facebook.com address as primary, since I wish to quickly check sent sample emails in their Facebook Messages inbox. However, I'm not allowed to do so [which makes sense, I guess, because the primary email id is supposed to be a non-FB one].

It's tiring to create a new email account for every test user [can't reuse the same email address, because Facebook complains that it's already being used for an account]

So I have two questions:

1. Where can emails sent to @tfbnw.net addresses be accessed?
2. How should I go about setting up distinct primary email accounts for my test users? [I know I could set up distinct GMail accounts and fwd them to my own, but that seems like a lot of work.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally resorted to using Mailcatcher. This ensures that I don't have any special logic in my app for test users and it allows me to immediately test how the email looks under html/text formatting.

http://mailcatcher.me/

Comment: How did this solve your problem of setting up email accounts for test users? I interested in doing this for the same reasons you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the test users to have reachable email addresses on Facebook's side?

You could just email arbitrary email addresses at a domain you control if you want to test how the emails look when sent out, or change the test users' email addresses to @yourdomain.com if your domain supports wildcard addresses like that

Comment: That requires changing the default email address on a test users account - which is a lot of work. I wanted something that tests out the entire flow, without me having to add special code that changes email addresses for test users. I finally resorted to using Mailcatcher

Answer (score 0):

If i log in as a test user for one of my apps, the “info” section of their profile shows `100003…2173648@facebook.com` as their contact email – so the basic `userid@facebook.com` address (userid since they have no username set).

And when I write an email to that address, immediately afterwards a new message notification shows up for the browser window that I’m “logged into” with this test account.

Comment: Hmm.. in my case, the `userid@facebook.com` email address is not default. I finally resorted to using Mailcatcher.

Comment: Oh yeah - it also does not allow me to set the primary email address to the Facebook one. Not sure if this is something peculiar to my experience though.